# Keyboard adjusting issue in react native for android

Tags: android, react-native, input, keyboard, adjustment

I'm a beginner to react native development and for keyboard handling in my current application, I have used `react-native-keyboard-manager` which works well in iOS. Now for android, it says I need to set `android:windowSoftInputMode` to adjustResize. I've tried both `adjustResize` and `adjustPan` as well but they both behave the same way and my view get squashed up. Below are the screenshots of my view.

**View before keyboard appearance**

[image]

**View after keyboard appearance**

[image]

Am I missing something here? Is there an easy way to fix this? I'm aware of other Libraries like KeyboardAvoidingView, KeyboardSpacer and KeyboardAwareScrollView, but if I use that I would need to implement it in every view and repeat same code to do it separately for android as in iOS it already works very well. Any help is appreciated

Comment: When you changed to `adjustPan` did you rebuild the project or did you just refresh the project using `RR`?

Comment: I just refreshed using RR, and now that you've mentioned it I tried rebuilding the project and it seems to be working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make changes to native code in your project then you **must** rebuild your project.

You will not see the updates in your simulator/emulator if you just reload it (ie pressing `CMD+R` or `RR`. This is due to the fact that when you reload all you are doing is changing the JavaScript and not the native code.

To effect the changes (usually the best way is to remove the previous build folder first) is to run `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` that way you force a rebuild and any changes to your native code are then updated on your simulator/emulator.